# Power Series Convergence

Tags: calculus, power-series

I have the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^{\frac{1}{n}}$$ and I want to test for convergence. So I wrote the series as
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty2\cdot2^{\frac{1}{n-1}}$$
But I'm not sure how to put this into the form of $\frac{a}{1-r}$. Any help?

Comment: **Hint:**  What is $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{\frac{1}{n}}$?

Comment: You can't. That form is for geometric series, which this isn't.

Comment: And, anyway, you got the exponent wrong when you factored out the $2$.

Comment: Ah, I see. So since lim doesn't = 0, the series is divergent?

Comment: Please do not delete questions which others have worked to answer and comment on. This is disrespectful of their effort and keeps others from benefiting from your question and its answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=c \implies a_n \to 0 $$
Check if $$2^\frac{1}{n}$$ converges to $0$